# How to fake declared services in Startup.cs during testing?

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, autofac

I would like to write integration tests for my Asp .net core application, but I don't want my tests to use real implemetation of some services.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddTransient<IExternalService,ExternalService>();
        ...
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public interface IExternalService
{
    bool Verify(int id);
}

public class ExternalService : IExternalService
{
    public bool Verify(int id)
    {
        //Implemetation is here.
        //I want to fake this implemetation during testing.
    }
}

[Fact]
public void TestCase()
{
    //Stub out service
    var myExtService = new Mock<IExternalService>();

    //Setup response by stub
    myExtService
        .Setup(p => p.Verify(It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(false);

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureServices((services) =>
        {
            //Setup injection
            services.AddTransient<IExternalService>((a) =>
            {
                return myExtService.Object;
            });
        });

    var server = new TestServer(host);

    var client = server.CreateClient();

    var response = client.GetAsync("/").Result;

    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    Assert.Contains("Your service returned: False", responseString);
}
```

Current injection setup in test case does not work, because ExternalService is injected over the mock.

However the test will pass when I remove `services.AddTransient<IExternalService,ExternalService>;` from `Startup`.

Most likely the one in `Startup` is called later and all the setup in that class is preferred by application.

**What options do I have to setup some dependecies in tests, but use everything else as they are declared in `Startup`?**

**UPDATE**

1. Application code should be unaware of tests.
2. Tests should be aware of:

   - (weakly typed) Endpoint - if this changes then test should fail
   - IExternalService interface
3. Tests should not care if application has razor pages or uses mvc or how the application is wired between endpoint and IExternalService.
4. Tests should not have to setup or configure application (apart from stubbing IExternalService) in order to make it work.

   - I understand that WebHostBuilder still has to be created, but my point is that configuration should be bare minimum in test case and majority of configuration should still be described on application side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only option I know of is to setup `WebHostBuilder` with `UseEnvironment`:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                //Setup injection
                services.AddTransient<IExternalService>(provider =>
                {
                    return myExtService.Object;
                });
            })
            .UseEnvironment("IntegrationTest");
```

And then add a condition in the `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (Configuration["Environment"] != "IntegrationTest")
        {
            services.AddTransient<IExternalService, ExternalService>();
        }

        services.AddMvc();

        // ...
    }
```

### **UPDATE:**

I did some more poking around and another option is to not use `UseStartup` extension method but rather configure the `WebHostBuilder` directly.  You can do this a number of ways but I thought that you could possibly create your own extension method to create a template in your tests:

```
public static class WebHostBuilderExt
{
    public static WebHostBuilder ConfigureServicesTest(this WebHostBuilder @this, Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
    {
        @this.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                configureServices(services);

                services.AddMvc();
            })
            .Configure(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseMvc();
            });
        return @this;
    }
}
```

Now your tests can be setup like the following:

```
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServicesTest(services =>
            {
                //Setup injection
                services.AddTransient<IInternalService>(provider =>
                {
                    return myExtService.Object;
                });
            });

        var server = new TestServer(host);
```

This means that you will have to explicitly setup all the implementations that the container will resolve for the specific endpoint you are calling.  You can choose to mock or use the the concrete implementations.

Comment: Yes that would work, but I would like to keep application unaware of tests. Currently system under test would crash during other tests that run in "IntegrationTest" environment and don't setup that dependecy.

Comment: Your update solves the problem of keeping application unaware of tests. However you are duplicating configuration in tests and that is a slippery slope. Test should be aware of endpoint and IExternalService and use minimum setup for application. Tests should not have setup mvc, because it is not its concern how system is wired between endpoint and IExternalService (I updated question).

Comment: You can create extension methods that both the Startup and Test call so that the configuration is centralized. But I do realize that I'm providing a workaround and not giving you a solution through the framework which you're looking for. Cheers,

Answer (score 8):

The only thing yo need to change is to use `ConfigureTestServices` instead of `ConfigureServices`. `ConfigureTestServices` runs after your `Startup`, therefor you can override real implementations with mocks/stubs. `ConfigureServices` was newer intended for that purpose, rather, it configures "host services", which are used during the host-building phase of the application, and copied into the application's DI container.

`ConfigureTestServices` is available in ASP Core version 2.1 and higher.

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
    {
        //Setup injection
        services.AddTransient<IExternalService>((a) =>
        {
            return myExtService.Object;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. At that time 2.x wasn't released. I'll need to review this question and solution for it.

Comment: @siim-haas Microsoft already released 2.1 (LTS) and 2.2 the only announced version that is still in preview is 3.0 which is scheduled somewhere in second half of 2019.

Comment: Perfect. WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices is called before Startup.ConfigureServices and WebHostBuilder.ConfigureTestServices is called after Startup.ConfigureServices

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of research I found a solution.

I could not find a way to solely use built-in dependency injection solution, so I opted to choose 3rd party DI solution - [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer)

Idea is to use WebHostBuilder (declared Main Program) and add necessary options so I can fake some services during testing.

Something that I learned:

- If you use Startup as `host.UseStartup<Startup>` it will be created after `host.ConfigureServices()`
- You cannot inject something to Startup like `host.UseStartup<Startup>(new Dependency())`
- However if you have registred dependency in `host.ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient<IDependency, MyDependency>())`, then it will be resolved before Startup is created and constructor `public Startup(IDependency dependency)` is used to create `Startup`.

My application side:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHost(args)
           .Build()
           .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((services) =>
            {
                //Setup autofac.
                services.AddAutofac();

                //Register module dependency that Startup requires.
                services.AddTransient<Module, MyAutofacModule>();

                ////It would a bit cleaner to use autofac to setup Startup dependency,
                ////but dependency did not get resolved for Startup.
                //services.AddAutofac((builder) =>
                //{
                //   builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
                //});
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

public class MyAutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //Register all application dependencies in this module.
        builder.Register((c) => new ExternalService()).As<IExternalService>();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    private Module applicationDIModule;

    public Startup(Module applicationDIModule)
    {
        this.applicationDIModule = applicationDIModule;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //We can add build-in services such as mvc and authorization,
        //but I would not use Add(Transient/Scoped/Singleton) here.
        //You should register domain specific dependecies in MyAutofacModule,
        //since it will be added after this method call.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    //This method is called after ConfigureServices (refer to Autofac link).
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //We will register injected module.
        builder.RegisterModule(applicationDIModule);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
public class IntegrationTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestCase()
    {
        //Create and setup moq object as usual.
        var service = new Mock<IExternalService>();
        service
            .Setup(p => p.Verify(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(false);

        //Bundle moq objects together for registration.
        var attachFakes = new Action<ContainerBuilder>((builder) =>
        {
            builder.Register(c => service.Object);
        });

        //Use host builder that application uses.
        var host = Program.CreateWebHost(new string[] { })
                          .UseContentRoot(GetContentRoot()) //Adjust content root since testproject.csproj is not in same folder as application.csproj
                          .ConfigureServices((services) =>
                          {
                              //We re-configure Module registration,
                              //so Startup is injected with our TestModule.
                              services.AddTransient<Module>((a) =>
                              {
                                  return new TestModule(attachFakes);
                              });
                          });

        //Create server to use our host and continue to test.
        var server = new TestServer(host);

        var client = server.CreateClient();

        var response = client.GetAsync("/").Result;

        var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Assert.Contains("External service result: False", responseString);
    }

    private static string GetContentRoot()
    {
        var current = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var parent = Directory.GetParent(current).Parent.Parent.Parent;
        return Path.Combine(parent.FullName, "src");
    }
}

public class TestModule : MyAutofacModule
{
    private Action<ContainerBuilder> attachFakes;

    public TestModule(Action<ContainerBuilder> attachFakes)
    {
        this.attachFakes = attachFakes;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //We register everything in MyAutoFacModule before adding our fakes.
        base.Load(builder);

        //We add fakes and everything that is re-registered here will be used instead.
        attachFakes.Invoke(builder);
    }
}
```

Although it feels a bit brittle, but I still prefer this solution over what @ODawg suggested. His solution would work, but I see it would cause troubles in future when new test cases are added.